# Dask Distributed - Same persist data multiple clients

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

We are trying Dask Distributed to make some heavy computes and visualization for a frontend.

Now we have one worker with gunicorn that connects to an existing Distributed Dask cluster, the worker uploads the data currently with `read_csv` and persist into the cluster.

I've tried using pickle to save the futures from the persist dataframe, but it doesn't work.

We want to have multiple gunicorn workers, each with a different client connecting to the same cluster and using the same data, but with more workers each one uploads a new dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are looking for Dask's abililty to [publish datasets](https://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/publish.html)

A convenient way to do this is to using the `client.datasets` mapping

Client 1

```
client = Client('...')
df = dd.read_csv(...)
client.datasets['my-data'] = df
```

Client 2..n

```
client = Client('...')  # same scheduler
df = client.datasets['my-data']
```

Comment: This is just was I needed 

Thank you very much!